# Customize Sql Server Object Explorer Right Click Menu Items

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I add or customize right click menu items in object explorer in Sql Server 2012?
for example I wanna add new items to table right click menu for generate my customize table creator script?

Comment: I'm curious to know what the "customize table creator script" does. It sounds intriguing. Do you intend to share this with the community?

Comment: Sql Server provide default create or alter script for object on right click menu.Consider we want do something before create or alter object,for example check exist object before create it.This will increase development team performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write an SSMS add-in.

See

http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jonsayce/archive/2008/01/15/building-a-sql-server-management-studio-addin.aspx

http://www.ssmsboost.com/create-own-ssms-2012-add-in-sample-code-with-download

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a project at Red Gate to open up our SSMS extensibility code. It sounds like it's exactly what you need and it's more straight-forward than interacting with SSMS directly.

There's a developer guide here: http://www.red-gate.com/ssmsecosystem/developerresources